# How to select from address using selenium and python?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

I am automating make my trip app for practicing. I am working on selenium and python
I am unable to enter from the address and select the autocomplete list.

here is the code

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

class PythonOrgSearch(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    def test_search_in_python_org(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com")
        fromaddress = driver.find_element_by_class_name('react-autosuggest__input react-autosuggest__input--open')
        fromaddress.send_keys('Bangalore')
        fromaddress.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
        fromaddress.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)




    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

[image]

Comment: Do you get an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first have to open the menu, by clicking on the From City text, using ID.

```
driver.find_element_by_id("fromCity").click()
```

Then you can query the autocomplete, but fixing the locator you used (only one class is necessary):

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".react-autosuggest__input--open")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think by class name only takes a single class not multiple.

You could try a css selector to find elements with two classes:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".react-autosuggest__input.react-autosuggest__input--open")
```

Or just only use one of the classes instead of both.